# React Native Navigator undefined when clicking a link

Tags: android, react-native

Fairly new to React and just following along to YouTube tutorials where I can. Having an issue with a navigation bar that I've imported into a screen. Clicking on any of the links results in an 'undefined' error.

My environment is

- React Native
- Android Development Studio (With simulator)
- VSCode to develop

Here are my files

App.js

```
import React, from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

// Menu and Navigation
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Navigator from './Screens/AppNavigator';

export default function App() {
  return (
       <NavigationContainer>
          <Navigator /> 
       </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

AppNavigator.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen  from './HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './ProfileScreen';

export default function AppNavigator() {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}  options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

ProfileScreen.js - **This has the content and the Navigation bar imported onto it.**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import ScreenStyles from './ScreenStyles';
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar/NavBar';

export default function ProfileScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={ScreenStyles.ScreenFramework}>
      <View style={ScreenStyles.ScreenContainer}>
        <View style={{ padding: 30 }}>
          <Text style={ScreenStyles.ScreenTitle}>Your Profile Page</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={ScreenStyles.NavBarContainer}>
          <NavBar />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

NavBar.js - When clicking a link, it throws an error **'Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined'**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import styles from './NavbarStyle';

export default function NavBar({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.NavBarContainer}>
        <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
          <View style={styles.ImageIcon}>
            <Image
              style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }}
              source={require('./img/home.png')} />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}>
            <View style={styles.ImageIcon}>
              <Image
                style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }}
                source={require('./img/profile.png')} />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I am wondering what I can do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either to pass navigation as a prop in  `<NavBar />` or use a hook as stated [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop)

Comment: Thanks Chefk5, that actually solved my issue. Curious though if this is the best way to handle a custom menu across multiple pages or if there is a better method?

Comment: Great! I always thought about it but I am not quite sure, to be honest. I did a quick search and found this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop